# How to add image from JSON array onto HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, json, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to create a slideshow where the images are hosted in an external JSON array, and loaded onto the html page and inserted onto a HTML5 canvas.

So far I am able to load all the images, but cannot add one image from the loaded Json images to the canvas.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = "utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="http://localhost/slideshow.css">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<title> JSON SlideShow </title>

</head>

<body>


<header>
<h1> JSON </h1>

<button id="btn"> GET </button>

<div id=slideshow"></div>
<p>Canvas:</p>
<canvas id="Canvas777" width="240" height="297" style="border:1px solid 
#d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>


<script src="http://localhost/slideshow.js"></script>

</header>    
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript attempt:

```
var slideContainer = document.getElementById("slideshow");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

var getImages = new XMLHttpRequest();
   getImages.open('GET', 'http://localhost/slideshow.json');
   getImages.onload = function() {
       var ourData = JSON.parse(getImages.responseText);
       renderHTML(ourData);    
       };
   getImages.send();

function renderHTML(data) {
var htmlString = "";
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
htmlString += "<img src=" + data[i].img + ">" + "</img>";   
}
slideContainer.insertAdjacentHTML ('beforeend', htmlString);
}

window.onload = function() {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(htmlString,10,10);
};
};
```

I know I am going wrong, but dont know how to fix it.

Comment: What is your desired outcome? And for clarification, you are currently loading ALL images, and this is working successfully, you just don't want that to happen?

Comment: @cmprogram my end goal is to create a slideshow in the canvas, that loads the images one by one and can be changed with next and previous button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the demo I'm using your data as a variable. Also I'm using only 2 images. Also I have to call the renderHTML() function.  You need to call this function with `getImages.onload` I hope it works for you.

Although Im using

```js
let data = [
  {
    img:
      "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/puppyBeagle300.jpg",
    msg: "There once was a kitten called Nina"
  },
  {
    img: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/puppyD300.jpg",
    msg: "Who was funny, silly"
  }
];

var slideContainer = document.getElementById("slideshow");
//var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

/*
var getImages = new XMLHttpRequest();
   getImages.open('GET', 'http://localhost/TMA1/part3/slideshow.json');
   getImages.onload = function() {
       var ourData = JSON.parse(getImages.responseText);
       renderHTML(ourData);    
       };
   getImages.send();*/

function renderHTML(data) {
  data.map(f => {
    loadImg(f.img).then(successurl => {
      let htmlString = '<img width="150" src="' + successurl + '" />';
      slideContainer.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", htmlString);
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = successurl;

      ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
    }),
      errorurl => {
        console.log("Error loading " + errorurl);
      };
  });
}

function loadImg(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let img = new Image();

    img.onload = () => {
      resolve(url);
    };

    img.onerror = () => {
      reject(url);
    };
    img.src = url;
  });
}


renderHTML(data);
```

```html
<button id="btn"> GET </button>

<div id="slideshow"></div>
<p>Canvas:</p>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="240" height="297" style="border:1px solid 
#d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
```

Comment: What do I need to remove from your code to make it work for me?

Comment: Instead of `renderHTML(data);`at the end of the JS use your `getImages = new XMLHttpRequest();.......`. And of course delete my `data` variable.

Comment: yay, that worked! now how do I make the image change to another image in the canvas with a click of a button?